# dynamically change width of div when portal gets narrower with css only

Tags: html, css

Is there a css based way (non-javascript) to make a div variable in width relative to the portal? I want the div to be about 50% of the portal width when the portal is above 1000px wide, but as the portal narrows, I want the div to get wider, not narrower, so I cannot just set div width to 50%. For example at 700px wide I'd like it to be about 58% of portal width.

Can this be done with css calc()? I'd like to avoid writing a lot of media query rules for each defined portal width and instead just have it be continuously adjusting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some Math to find the formula.  `x = a*W + b` where `W` is the portal width and  `x` your element width.

For `W=1000px` we need `x=500px` --> `500px = a*1000px + b`

For `W=700px` we need `x=406px (0.58*700px)` --> `406px = a*700px + b`

After few math we will get: `a = 0.313` and `b = 187px`

so you use `calc(31.3% + 187px)` and we can consider a `max-width` with it

```css
.portal {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.portal div {
  width: calc(31.3% + 187px);
  max-width: min(500px,100%); /* not bigger than 500px and 100% of the portal width*/
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="portal">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Basically the formula is a percentage + a fixed width and the fixed part is the one that will make your element getting wider in percentage since it's fixed.

Comment: This is helpful! Though must say I'm getting an error when parsing the line: max-width: min(500px,100%); "Internal Error: Incompatible units: '%' and 'px'"

Comment: @Ben you are probably using an old tool that don't recognize new CSS feature. As you can in the snippet above, it works fine

Comment: Ah you're right Temani, seems like an issue with sass implementation and not css spec: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#min-and-max